# Standard docType for RootPanel and RootLayoutPanel in GWT

Tags: gwt, doctype, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I used TabLayoutPanel widget in my GWT project but it is not working in ie. somewhere i read if i use RootLayoutPanel instead of RootPanel it will work. but for usnig RootLayoutPanel I should use some standard doctype in my html page.

which of doctype i can use in my GWT project?

RGDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards) for the GWT 2.0 layout system.